# Custom UI rendering in Webview

Tags: webview, custom-ui

How can we render a custom UI in a Web application when we load the page in iOS and Android WebViews?

I tried to open a webapp in a webview like this.

```
guard let url = URL(string: "https://www.abcd.com/") else {
  return
}
wkWebView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
```

Now, if I want to add a custom button in the web page for the mobile app alone? How that can be achieved.

Comment: Found a way, this could be achieved by setting up a customUserAgent property of WKWebView., this property will be retrieved from the WebApp end, based on the user agent the web developers can take the decision to redirect to desired page.